# Customising two-part chapter titles with titlesec

Tags: chapters, titlesec

I have a question about the formatting of chapter titles with `titlesec`.

I would like my chapter titles to broadly adhere to the `display` option similar to the one in this example, based on the code found [here](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Sections_and_chapters).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter}
[display]
{\bfseries\large\itshape}
{\center{\thechapter}}
{0.5ex}
{
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vspace{1ex}
\centering
}
[
\vspace{-0.5ex}
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3pt}
]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Sample Chapter}
\end{document}
```

This produces something like this:

[image]
Instead of the '1', however, I would like to be able to insert a customisable text, for example 'Introduction'. How would I go about something like this, ideally still with the help of `titlesec`?

Cheers!